# Treeview implementation child nodes missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, xmldocument

```
private void AddNode(XmlNode inXmlNode, TreeNode inTreeNode)
 {
    XmlNode xNode;
    TreeNode tNode;
    XmlNodeList nodeList;
    int i = 0;
    if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
    {
        nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;
        for (i = 0; i <= (nodeList.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];
            if (null != xNode)
            { 
                inTreeNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Attributes[0].Value));                        
                tNode = inTreeNode.ChildNodes[i];  
                AddNode(xNode, tNode);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        inTreeNode.Text = inXmlNode.InnerText.ToString();
    }
}
```

But am getting only parent node and child nodes are not added . After going through various sites i learned that this is the error

```
inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Attributes[0].Value));                        
                        tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[i];
```

but am not getting inTreeNode.Nodes option.

Thanks for Help

Answer (score 0):

Nodes collection is at treeview level and try to look the implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640376/adding-parent-and-child-nodes-in-treeview-from-sql-server-2008?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for reply ... It still doesnt add the ChildNodes